# Should I learn Swift or Objective C for iOS

Tags: objective-c, swift

I've just learnt objective c for the purpose of app building for iOS. In fact i started tinkering this week with my first attempt at an app, I was unaware about Swift and I am reading the text blog on the WWDC.

Going forward, should I be looking to build apps in Swift rather than Objective C now? And are the languages fairly similar?

I ask mainly because I've only just learnt the syntax for Objective-C and done little playing around with it, so dropping it all together isn't too much of a big deal for me. What's more important is that I use the right language. I got my first mac only a few months ago and I've not had much experience with Apple so I thought I'd go to place where people who are far more experienced all round could help point me in the right direction. I don't know if Swift means that it's likely Objective-C will be dropped entirely at some point.

Comment: swift documentation and examples from apple are abysmal to say the least. go with swift by a longshot unless you like archaic obfuscated code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This answer won't stand the test of time, but as of today:

- Objective-C will be around and supported for a long time.  (Apple has a massive amount of Objective-C source code that it's not going to port to Swift any time soon.)
- Almost all iOS tutorials, examples, and books use Objective-C.
- Almost all iOS-specific third-party source code you might want to use is implemented in Objective-C.
- It's easier to use C and C++ libraries from Objective-C than from Swift.
- There are many Objective-C experts you can get help from.  There are very few Swift experts.
- The Swift language and its standard library are currently not very well documented.

Stick with Objective-C for now.  When you're comfortable with the iOS SDK and Swift is better documented, you can consider learning Swift.

#### UPDATE

It's been four months and my opinion on this hasn't changed.  If you're looking for a more recent answer, this Hacker News thread was asked and answered today: [Is Swift ready for production?](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8887545)

Comment: +1 Totally agree. Swift is a very nice language, but so is Objective-C. With all the content available for Objective-C you have a lot more resources available.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks Rob, I think that people who are just entering iOS development will be pleased to find your answer as investing any amount of time in learning a language or new skill set is time well spent. Or badly spent if it's soon obsolete.