# Should I learn object-c to before learning swift?

Tags: swift

I learn C/C++ and Java but I do not know Object-C.

Should I learn ojb-c first before learning Swift language?

Comment: Learn them both. Learn as much as you can.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I learn Swift or Objective C for iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750495/should-i-learn-swift-or-objective-c-for-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to do some experiments with iOS / MacOS you would consider using Swift. It is modern and personally I feel it is simpler. If you want to develop software you want to puplish you would consider doing that right with Objective-C. Swift is not enough mature for doing that at the moment.